# Box plots showing relationship in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I am using a regression model for some data whose explanatory variables can only be `1,2,3,4 and 5`. There are 5 explanatory variables and a dependent variable. For example,

```
set.seed(2)
x1 <- sample(rep(1:5,2))
x2 <- sample(rep(1:5,2))
x3 <- sample(rep(1:5,2))
x4 <- sample(rep(1:5,2))
x5 <- sample(rep(1:5,2))
y <- runif(10,-1,1)

model <- lm(y~x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)
```

I want to create a box plot showing the relationship between these dependent variables  and the dependent variable. How can I do that in R?

I have managed to create a box plot using the code provided by @Ben. However, there are some points in the plot that I do not understand. Any idea what they are for? Here is the plot[image]

Comment: Draw us an image of what you expect to get. This may help you in providing a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: An example has been added. However, I don't know what the output would be like. I have been asked to create a boxplot showing the relationship between these dummy variables and y.

Comment: Are your x1, x2 ,x3 really a "dummy variables" because in regression analysis "dummy variables" usually consist of values 0 and 1 but in your data they contain values 1:5.

Comment: @didzis, you are right. I meant to say they can only be 1,2,3,4 and 5. I have edited.

Comment: It looks like your data are fairly strongly skewed, and that you have a large data set.  You might try substituting `geom_violin` for `geom_boxplot` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a boxplot, you'll have to explain in much more detail what you want it to be based on. (That is, this is a *programming* site; you would need to say how you wanted the results of the regression to be translated into the parameters of a boxplot (central line, fences, whiskers, etc.).)

That said, you can use the `coefplot` function in the `arm` package to draw a graphical summary

```
library(arm)
coefplot(model)
```

[image]

Or, on second thought, maybe the model is a red herring: maybe you just want to plot the data.

```
d <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
library(reshape2)
dm <- melt(d,id.var=1)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dm,aes(x=value,y=y))+geom_boxplot(aes(group=value))+
    facet_wrap(~variable,nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the second is the response to my question because I need this plot for exploratory data analysis. Cheers @Ben :)

Comment: I will ask a questions about the plot I have generated. Therefore, I need to upload my plot here. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and click on the relevant button in the edit controls to upload an image file.

Comment: @Ben, in my plot there are some points. I googled this and saw that they show the outliers. Is that right? Also, how can I name the x and y axes. I tried `xlab`  and `ylab`, but they do not work. Any idea?

Comment: either `+xlab("x title")+ylab("y title")`, or `+labs(x="x title",y="y title")`, right after `facet_wrap(...)`.  Yes, those are "outliers", but in a very special sense: see `?boxplot.stats`

Comment: @Ben, I am wondering whether it is possible to produce a box plot for the same explanatory variables, but for a dummy response variable `y <- rbinom(10,1,0.5)`. Is this possible? If so, can you please give some clue?